# Grouping rows in R based on numbers

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one column is the site number, but each site number is repeated 5 times, this is some of it:

```
Site<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Species1<-c(5,1,9,2,2,7,5,6,4,9)
Species2<-c(0,2,7,5,0,4,8,4,1,5)
Species3<-c(3,2,1,0,5,1,1,6,2,4)
```

There are 50 sites, each repeated five times (data was collected at those sites on five different days). I want to group the rows with the same site number to be able to calculate species numbers at those sites. This should create 1 row for each site.
Edit:

```
 Site<-c(1,2)
 Species1<-c(19,31)
 Species2<-c(14,22)
 Species3<-c(11,14)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `DF = data.frame(Site,Species1,Species2,Species3)` then `aggregate(.~Site,DF,sum)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.   We group by 'Site' and get the `sum` of all the other columns using `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Site) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

---

or with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, group by 'Site', we loop (`lapply(.SD,..`) through the columns and get the `sum`.

```
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Site]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Site, Species1, Species2, Species3)
```